# What does "skip it to the left" mean in Vim?

Tags: vim, paredit

I'm trying to figure out paredit. I'm seeing this in the documentation:

> When about to delete a (, ), [, ], or " and there are other
>                      characters inside, then just skip it to the left.

I have `((blah (blah blah)))` and I want `(blah (blah blah))`

Comment: Maybe "skip it to the left" means that you should use the % key to make sure your cursor is on the left parenthesis before proceeding? It's hard to tell without further context.

Comment: What is paredit, in the context of Vim?